# How to transfer one user's rep to another (same person, different accounts)?

Tags: support, reputation, merge-accounts

Can one user's reputation points be transferred to another user name, assuming that both are the same user?

Comment: Ask a ♦ to merge them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send an E-Mail to `team@stackoverflow.com` and ask them to merge the accounts. Alternatively, flag one of your contributions for moderator attention, and explain the situation in the text field.

I think the accepted way to show to the team that you control both accounts has been writing "please merge me with account xyz" into the "about me" box, but they will surely tell you what to do.

Comment: The "about me" on the account you want to go away once merged :)